# xcode 4 add CoreData in a existing project

Tags: xcode, core-data, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4

I am trying to include the framework CoreData to an existing Cocos2D project and I have the problem that the .sqlite file don't get created.

I copied the auto generated code from the "AppDelegate" from another project (with CoreData), included the framework by adding a "link binary with libraries" and renamed the "modelURL", further i added the ".xcdatamodeld" file

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Where does it fail? There are a lot of working parts to get Core Data to work.

Comment: Clean and run your project, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app delegate code from the template projects does not generate a persistent store file until you actively call the managedObjectContext property while the app is running. Normally, the persistence file doesn't show at all during build and it normally doesn't appear in Xcode at all.